# remove notification vibrate when vibrating is turn off android

Tags: android, notifications, vibration

I want to turn off vibrate in my app. I use this code:

`final AudioManager aManager;
aManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
aManager.setRingerMode(aManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);`

It works, but it show notification vibrate. How to turn off vibrate, without it show notifications. Can i do that?

Thanks for your attention